# Maximum of minimums in spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, apache-spark-sql

In Apache Spark 2.0+ how do I find the maximum of minimums, in the following problem:

```
df1
+---+---+
| id| ts|
+---+---+
|  1| 20|
|  2| 15|
+---+---+

df2

+---+---+
| id| ts|
+---+---+
|  1| 10|
|  1| 25|
|  1| 36|
|  2| 25|
|  2| 35|
+---+---+
```

the desired dataframe is:

```
+---+---+
| id| ts|
+---+---+
|  1| 10|
|  2| 15|
+---+---+
```

Problem in words: For every `id` in `df1` pick the maximum `ts` value that is lesser than the `ts` value in `df1`, if no such value exists, just print the `ts` value in `df1`.

Comment: Could supplement this code request with your current attempts, please? Also, please read [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915).

Answer (score 1):

Just aggregate join and select with `when` otherwise:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, max as max_

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 20),(2, 15)], ("id", "ts")
 )
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 10), (1, 25), (1, 36), (2, 25), (2, 35)], ("id", "ts")
)

ts = when(
    col("df2.ts") < col("df1.ts"), col("df2.ts")
).otherwise(col("df1.ts")).alias("ts")

(df2
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(max_("ts").alias("ts")).alias("df2")
    .join(df1.alias("df1"), ["id"])
    .select("id", ts)
    .show())

# +---+---+                                                                       
# | id| ts|
# +---+---+
# |  1| 20|
# |  2| 15|
# +---+---+
```

If not all ids have equivalents in `df2` use right outer join:

```py
.join(df1.alias("df1"), ["id"], "right")
```

and adjust `ts` to

```py
ts = coalesce(when(
    col("df2.ts") < col("df1.ts"), col("df2.ts")
).otherwise(col("df1.ts")), col("df1.ts")).alias("ts")
```